# store and retrieve tgz file in postgres using python psycopg2

Tags: python-3.6, psycopg2, postgresql-9.4

I have got a requirement where I need to store a compressed file in the tgz format(ex: my_folder.tgz) and at the same time, some other python process needs to fetch the tgz file using python psycopg2. I'm not able to find any document of psycopg2 for doing it.

Comment: Postgres is RDS, so it requires data to put into a table. I think if you need to store tgz file, just use some directories is fine.

Comment: You can use a bytea type column and use psycopg2's Binary function to insert the data into the database. 

https://www.psycopg.org/docs/module.html?highlight=binary#psycopg2.Binary